# Using marker symbol to point at the polygon instead of the leader line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, markers, leader-line

I am labelling polygons in ArcMap (10.5, standart licence, using Maplex). In case the label does not fit in the polygon I want to use **marker symbol (triagle, like an arrow) to point! at the polygon** the label refers to - to use this **instead of the leader line**

- for what I want it to look like *see green triangles on the right picture* (triangle being next to the label and pointing the direction where the "label's" polygon is!!) (vs clasical arrow leader line - see black line with red arrow on the left picture):

[image]

- I **tried**  to use **leader with line decoration** (like on the left pict.) to make it arrow leader and chosen the color of the leader line to *white* and the smallest line width ("*no color*" led in leader nor triangle showed up!). That actually helped but the **tringle** stayed (as expected) at the same position - but it **needs to be next to the label!**
- I **thought of** finding a way how to **set a leader line length** and setting that to a really small number so that it was not (or barely) visible - but did not find the way to make this possible to set;
  see also [Way to set a label leader line length (not using annotation) in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260708/way-to-set-a-label-leader-line-length-not-using-annotation-in-arcgis-desktop)

I want just *one marker sign per label*.
The solution should be useful also for situations where all the labels cannot be at the same direction from the polygon.
I cannot use annotations for this unless the whole thing stays dynamic.
I do not want the labels to be too far from the polygon border, say max. offset around 25 pts (to be able to place the arrow too).

Answer (score 2):

I hope i understand what you want.

**Option1:**
 - Open Layer properties and select Label tab
 - select symbol button
 - select edit symbol
 - select Advanced text tab (The below Image)

[image]
 - Under the Text Background button, click properties.You see the editor

window.Select marker Text Background (Show in the below image)

[image]

- Select Symbol button. type "triangle" and search symbols.
  [image]
- click ok twice. In the editor window, General Tab, you can change the triangle symbol position with X offset and Y offset.

[image]

**Opthion 2:**

Create a new label class :

- layer properties => label tab => Method: Define classes of features and label...
  [image]
- Click **Add** button and create a new label class.
- Label this class with **text background** (select a triangle symbol) same as the option1. In the general tab of the Editor window, change color to No color.
- Set **default** label class to your labels (text). 
  Now you can change positions and other settings of these two labels:
  Layer Properties => Label tab =>Label styles 
  In Label Style Selector window => click properties => Placement Properies.

Comment: I edited my Answer. The result is something like the last image. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Ok. @Abc1 I don't know what's your maplex setting. I recommend another solution. I edited my answer.

Comment: Option2 is not same as the option1. If you want to change the direction and position of the triangle, With Option2 you can it.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT SOLVE THE THING TO POINT AT THE POLYGON (the label cannot be at the same direction from the polygon every time!) + 1)option1 has a mistake - in general tab using x or y offset moves the whole thing not the marker symbol (at least since 10.3 that has been same) - moving marker symbol can be done from the "symbol selector" window shown on the 3rd pict. in option1 going to edit symbol and x resp. y offset;   2)option2: did not find a way how to make the text + the arrow stay together