# Way to set a label leader line length (not using annotation) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.5, leader-line

How to set a label leader line length without using annotation in ArcMap 10.5?

- I am using label leaders mainly for labelling features - pointing at the polygon/line/point that the label refers to.

I use Labelling Toolbar - Label Manager, than go to Symbol (/Edit Symbol/3rd tab - Advanced Text/Text Background - Properties) .... Line Callout/Leader Symbol (/Edit Symbol/Cartographic Line Symbol) ..., using simple line or arrow line mainly

example:
[image]

In this example I have set an offset that determine how far the label from the polygon border would be, but **I cannot set internal zones** (going from the dialog on picture bellow to properties and on the 1st tab internal zones) to influence where the leader will have it's end... **which would I think answer that question - so I am looking for another way to do it.**

[image]

illustration

[image]

Comment: Leader lines are available in several places. Are you using them for feature labels, dataframe extents, or something else? How precisely are you placing them now?

Comment: @PolyGeo for labelling features, edited Q. what do you mean by the last Q?

Comment: Sometimes potential answerers of a question may never have used the function being asked about. If you start by describing how you are using it (which option on which dialog, include a picture, etc) then it may encourage them to test and perhaps spot something you had overlooked. The clearer you can describe what you have tried and where you are stuck, the more likely it is that a potential answerer will be attracted to your question.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding (without going back to the documentation or testing) is that leaderlines are used to show where labels (that have been moved) have been moved from.

The overpost settings control how far labels can move so they would seem also to control how long the leader lines can be.

Comment: Yes, the leader line goes from the label to the feature, so you need to change the offset in the label settings to change its length.